# How to init MPMoviePlayerController with video paused

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm developing an app for iOS where it shows a movie, my method is a class method this is the code

Functions.m

```
static   MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = nil;
+(void)playMP4Movie:(NSString *)moviename
       insideOfView:(UIView *)view
           autoplay:(BOOL)autoplay{

    NSString *path          = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:moviename ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *videoURL         = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    moviePlayer             = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    moviePlayer.repeatMode  = MPMovieRepeatModeOne; // for looping
    moviePlayer.view.frame  = view.bounds;

    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    if (autoplay)   { [moviePlayer play]; }
    else            { [moviePlayer stop];  }

    [view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
}
```

and where I want to call it with video paused:

```
[Functions playMP4Movie:videoName insideOfView:_videoPlayerView autoplay:NO];
```

it shows my video but no matter if I set autoplay to YES or NO, the result is always the same... any help I'll appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
if (autoplay)   { [moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES]; }
else            { [moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:NO]; }
```

And see if you have better luck.